# 2 columns from one column with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a single column like this:

| numberhouse |
| --- |
| 654654 |
| 654653 |
| 654654 |
| 321323 |

I need to select the final digit. If the digit is `3` then place it in one column and if its `4` then place it in a second column.

I tried this:

```
SELECT (Right(numberhouse,1) WHERE ((Right(numberhouse,1))=3)) AS address3, (Right(numberhouse,1) WHERE ((Right(numberhouse,1))=4)) AS address4
FROM houseingsheet
```

I get the two columns I want, but there are no rows.

I want an output like this:

| address3 | address4 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |

How can I do this?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid SQL. What db are you using?

Comment: I'm using DBeaver

Comment: SELECT Right(numberhouse,1) AS address3, Right(numberhouse,1) AS address4
FROM houseingsheet
WHERE (((Right(numberhouse,1))=3) AND ((Right(numberhouse,1))="4"));


produces the two columns however they are empty

Comment: Telling us you use `DBeaver` is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the brand you see on the dashboard radio. Fine for most, but alarming from a mechanic.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, depending on what kind of database you're using (DBeaver is **NOT** a database; it's a tool for connecting and working with a database):

```
SELECT t1.address3, t2.address4
FROM (

    SELECT '3' as address3, row_number() over (order by  numberhouse) rn
    FROM housingsheet
    WHERE numberhouse like '%3'

) t1

FULL JOIN (

    SELECT '4' as address4, row_number() over (order by numberhouse) rn
    FROM housingsheet
    WHERE numberhouse like '%4'

) t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```

But I'd consider it an abuse of SQL and your database platform. This is not how relational data is meant to work.

Better practice at the database level is to simply select the values you need, like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(numberhouse, 1) as digit FROM housingsheet
```

To return this result:

| digit |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 3 |

Or like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN numberhouse like '%3' THEN '3' END as address3, 
       CASE WHEN numberhouse like '%4' THEN '4' END as address4
FROM housingsheet
```

To get this result:

| address3 | address4 |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | 4 |
| 3 | NULL |
| NULL | 4 |
| 3 | NULL |

Either of those are more typical for a database. Then you can format those results however you want with whatever columns in the client code or reporting tool.

Comment: Thanks, sorry MySql through DBeaver

this works a bit

address3   123m
3                 1
3                 2
3                 3

i'm confused where the 123m comes from and the result in that column, there is no "1" in the datashee

Comment: Which version of MySql? Also, MySql does not support `FULL JOIN`, so you'll need to find a work-around.

Comment: Perfect, that hits the spot, thank you so much for you help!